# Activerecord - rails generate model M_Name f_name:string --> get VARCHAR column type instead of nvarchar

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, t-sql, activerecord

I'm making a new web app using Rails. I created a restaurant model:

```
rails generate model Restaurant name:string{50}
rails db:migrate
```

In my new table `:restaurants` my field `:name` has been created and its column type is nvarchar(50)

I was wondering how can I generate a **varchar(50)** column type instead a **nvarchar(50)** by using rails command?

Comment: what adapter  gem is using for DB connection?

Comment: Not that i see a reason why. Even if you're 100% sure the names are pure ASCII this seems a bad idea.

    rails generate model Restaurant 'name:varchar{50}'

Should do it, but some adapters don't like that syntax, you might have to fix the limit option in the resulting migration.

      t.varchar :name, limit:50

Comment: Hi Oleksii, I use activerecord gem: gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'

Comment: Thanks Neongrau but I think varchar is not an option for field:type

Comment: I'm using Postgres in my projects, so I not big expert in tsql, but - little investigation in git repo of gem (https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/search?p=2&q=string&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93), and some reading about what is nvarchar in this database, pushed me to a thought that this column type sect the adapter gem - and Im pretty shure that this selection based on your database configuration. Think your db is in unicode, so nvarchar is selected by default. This is not rails option.